# how do i create a binary [0,1]?

Tags: matlab, optimization, binary

i want to declare that x will be variable for binary 0,1

i and k represent facilities in flow matrix, j and q represent location in distance matrix ..

x(i,j) mean that x will be equal to 1 if i (facility) is assign in j (location) ..

x(i, j) = 1 if facility i is assigned to location j and if otherwise, xij = 0, 
so otherwise mean that if x(k,q) =1 , x(i,J) will be 0...

example of the manual calculation

Min =(f i1,k1 * d j1,q1 * x i1,j1 * x k1,q1) + (f i1,k1 * d j1,q2 * x i1,j1 * x k1,q2) + (f i1,k1 * d j1,q3 * x i1,j1 * x k1,q3)....

( 0*0* 1*1 ) + ( 0* 6* 1*0 ) + ( 0*8 * 1 *0 ).....

I want to *xi1,j1 * xk1,q1 to be 0 or 1.. if i choose i1, j1=1 the other will be 0.. for example i2,j1 will be equal to 0

below is the coding

```
clc;
clear;
%sum sum sum sum(fik*djq*xij*xkq)
%i,k= facilities
%j,q= location
%f(i,k)= flow between facilities i and k
%d(j,q)= distance between locations j and q
%xij = 1 if facility i is assigned to location j and if otherwise, xij = 0
% Flow matrix: flow assigning facility i (column) to facility k (row)
f = [0 5 7 9;
     5 0 4 6;
     7 4 0 3;
     9 6 3 0];
%Distance matrix: distance assigning location j (column) to location q (row)
d = [0 6 8 9;
     6 0 5 1;
     8 5 0 2;
     9 1 2 0];
 z= 0;
 nf= 4;
 nd= 4;
 for i=1:nf 
     for j=1:nf 
         for k=1:nd 
             for q=1:nd 
                 z = min('z','f(i,k)*d(j,q)*x(i,j)*x(k,q)'); 
             end
         end
     end
 end
%Constraints
%The first set of constraints requires that each facility gets exactly one 
%location, that is for each facility, the sum of the location values 
%corresponding to that facility is exactly one
 Constraints.constr1 = sum(x,2) == 1;
%The second set of constraints are inequalities. These constraints specify 
%that each office has no more than one facility in it.
 Constraints.constr2 = sum(x,1) == 1;
 disp (z);
```

Comment: You want to use `logical`.

Comment: do you said that i need to used logical?

Comment: Yes, [`logical`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logical.html). It is MATLAB's binary type. If you want `x` to be binary (0 or 1), you want to make it logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using recperm

this recperm is used to fine permuation 0,1 in the coding